# center row content in bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I know this question has been asked a lot but each one seems to be a bit unique and I have tried at least 7 different versions here on StackOverflow and none have worked.

It should be a simple fix but I can't center the div contents. I need all the rows centered to the gird and centered when scaled all the way down to the mobile view.

Here is my code example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOBJEv

Here is the html:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/image-333x333.jpg" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top"> <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png"> </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">cheese </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Ed-Vizenor-150x150.jpg" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top"> <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png"> </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">Cool Beans </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/BeauBird-150x150.png" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top"> <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png"> </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">I am happy </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ave4-150x150.jpg" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top"> <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png"> </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">Hello world! </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this `.text-center{text-align:center !important;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the `.row-fluid{...}` and `div.bottom{...}` code blocks to your existing CSS.

```css
.row-fluid {
  text-align: center;
}
div.bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0px;
}
.topic {} .bottom {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  max-width: 275px;
  min-width: 277px;
}
.img-btm {
  height: 233px;
  width: 228px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 233px;
  -moz-border-radius: 233px;
  border-radius: 233px;
}
.bottom .text-center {
  max-width: 275px;
  min-width: 277px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/image-333x333.jpg" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top">
      <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png">
    </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">cheese</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Ed-Vizenor-150x150.jpg" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top">
      <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png">
    </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">Cool Beans</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/BeauBird-150x150.png" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top">
      <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png">
    </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">I am happy</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <img src="http://edvizenor.com/2015/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ave4-150x150.jpg" class="img-btm">

    <div class="top">
      <img src="http://www.edvizenor.com/2015/images/TopicCircleBlue.png">
    </div>
    <div class="topic text-center">Hello world!</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**source:** [Bootstrap 3 responsive centered columns](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns)

---

Source has no explanation for the code, so

The class **`.row-fluid`** has a `text-align:center` property which makes its contents centered.

Under **`div.bottom`** I have the `display:inline-block` property which is necessary for its parents text-align property to work; `float:none` overrides the default `float:left` and `text-align:left` is a fix for center positioning the image inside the column div, because there was some padding to the element.

Comment: can you specify what you updated, in your answer, that will help others who is searching for similar problem :)